# Re-create UISwitch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, subclass, uiswitch

My client doesn't like the gloss on the iOS 5 UISwitch, and wants me to create a non glossy version using some images. However I don't know how I would go a bouts this.

I have created a UIView Subclass and I don't know what to do next.

Any suggestions as to what I need to do next?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can recreate `UISwitch` using CoreGraphics (without using images).

Have a look at this: [DCRoundSwitch](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCRoundSwitch)

DCRoundSwitch is designed to be a drop in replacement for `UISwitch`.

In any case you should create a `UIControl` subclass!

Comment: DCRoundSwitch is good and I've used it in a project, but i think it's not exactly a drop-in replacement of UISwitch - it's missing any kind of InterfaceBuilder integration.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to do what you want. One way is to use a UIImageView and just switch the image when the user taps on the control.

Something like:

```
-(void) loadView
{
  [super loadView];

  UIImageView *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1-from-client"];
  UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1] autorelease];
  imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  [self.view addSubview:imageView];

  // detect the tap
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)] autorelease];
  [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}

// this gets called when the user taps
-(void) tap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
  UIImageView *viewTapped = (UIImageView*)gesture.view;
  if ( viewTapped.tag == 0 )
  {
     viewTapped.tag = 1;
     viewTapped.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2-from-client"];
  }
  else
  {
     viewTapped.tag = 0;
     viewTapped.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1-from-client"];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate a custom `UISwitch` by subclassing `UIControl`. Then you can use regular UIViews to create almost any effect you want. You can look take a look at `SevenSwitch`. A  custom `UISwitch` replacement I've created. It is non-glossy and the colors can be customized to you're liking.

https://github.com/bvogelzang/SevenSwitch

Comment: @TMin the person was posting identical answers - they have been deleted.